# Why does String.append not work for formatted strings like "foo\(bar)"?

Tags: swift, swift3

While implementing `CustomStringConvertible` I encountered an error I don't quite understand.

```
struct Name {
    let name: String?
}

extension Name: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var desc = ""
        if let name = name {
            desc.append("Page: \(name)")
        }
        return desc
    }
}
```

This leads to the following errors:

```
error: cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)'
note: overloads for 'append' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (UnicodeScalar), (Character)
```

It looks like the compiler doesn't know which implementation of the `append` function to use.

Changing it to

```
desc.append(name)
```

works fine. As does

```
desc.appendContentsOf("Page: \(name)")
```

Why is that exactly?

Comment: `desc.append(name)` does not compile, `append()` takes a single character or Unicode scalar.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string) refers to `func append(String)` that takes a string. If you read my example, you can also see that it works for appending a String.

Comment: That documentation refers to Swift 3. Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Swift 2.2 so `append(String)` does not work for me. Must be something they added to Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Swift 2,** `String` has two `append` methods, which take a single
character or Unicode scalar as an argument:

```
public mutating func append(c: Character)
public mutating func append(x: UnicodeScalar)
```

That's why `desc.append("Page: \(name)")` does not compile
(and `desc.append(name)` does not compile either). But

```
public mutating func appendContentsOf(other: String)
```

appends another string. Alternatively use

```
desc += "Page: \(name)"
```

In **Swift 3,** those methods have been renamed to

```
public mutating func append(_ other: Character)
public mutating func append(_ other: UnicodeScalar)
public mutating func append(_ other: String)
```

and then it is

```
desc.append("Page: \(name)")
```

Comment: @orkoden: You have tagged your question with Swift 3 now. But in Xcode 8 beta 6, your original code with `desc.append("Page: \(name)")` compiles for me as well.

Comment: The strange thing is, I was using Xcode 7.3.1 so I didn't expect Swift 3 to play a role. Now that I tried again `desc.append(name)` was not working. So it seems like there was some kind of confusion by playground or something.

Comment: @orkoden: In my experience, a Playground is great to play with *working* code. As soon as anything goes wrong and you don't see why, use a compiled project. The error messages and debugging facilities are better.